# Unable to format/wipe Window Disk without Error (Tried Ubuntu Gparted and Diskpart

Tags: windows, partitioning, gparted, microsoft-surface, diskpart

I am trying to wipe/reinstall Windows, however, all have no success.

In usb live boot to Window installation set up, install new Window to override it, unable to delete or format any of my exisiting disk/partition.

I then tried repair your computer -> Troubleshoot -> Command Prompt and wiping with disk part

```
select disk 0
Disk 0 is now the selected disk
clean
Diskpart Succeeded in cleaning the disk.
create partition primary
Virtual Disk Service error:
There is not enough usable space for this operation.
list partition
(All partitions are not clean, still the same as before)
```

I also tried wiping it with Gparted using Ubuntu live boot.

1. Open Gparted.
2. Select Any of my Window's partition
3. Delete
4. Apply Operations
5. All operations successfully completed
6. Gparted refreshes and the partition is still there and not deleted.

Attempt on fdisk

```
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
d
3 (any number, doesnt matter)
Partition 3 has been deleted
w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to reread partition table.
Syncing Disks.
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
p
(All disk are still there)
```

Comment: If this is an SSD then chances are the flash is corrupt and has become read only. Replace the disk.

Comment: Did you / can you try FDISK to delete all partitions and then see if you can install Windows (Windows 10 will make at least 3 partitions including the main partition.

Comment: @Mokubai, yes, it is an ssd and everything I have tried seems that everything is indeed read only. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnI have attempted fdisk, seems just like any other attempt, it shows successful, but didnt work. I have added my attempt above.  As Mokubai mentioned above, it could have been a ssd flash corrupted issue.

Comment: It appears to be a drive error at this point.